# How to use Mac finder import image with Python executable

Tags: python, finder

I already finished my project source code. The code is basically about analysis an image. However, I am currently using `cv2.imread()` to import the image to source code.

I am expecting that user can choose image from Mac finder after I convert the source code to executable.

Basically what I want is:
When user open the executable, Mac finder will show up and user can choose image from it.

I really don't know what to do to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use tkinter and file dialog to open a finder menu as follows:

```
from tkinter import filedialog, Tk

root = Tk()
root.withdraw()

path = filedialog.askopenfilename()
```